# Encoding/Decoding matrices as integers, integers as matrices

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, number-representation

I want to convert large binary matrices of m x n dimensions into integers, and then to convert these integers to the original matrices.

I attempted the following:

```
testArray = {{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 
   0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 
   1, 1, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}; 
 code = FromDigits[Flatten[testArray, 1], 2];
 reconstructArray = ArrayReshape[IntegerDigits[code, 2], {8, 7}];

Equal[testArray, reconstructArray]
```

which outputs `False`

Comment: `IntegerDigits[code, 2]` is only 55-long. To fit this list into an $8\times7$ array, `ArrayReshape` pads it by adding a zero *at the end*, which of course is equivalent to multiplying the encoded number by $2$ in your application. You will need to take care of the padding explicitly for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

Use the third argument to `IntegerDigits` to specify the length of the digit sequence required, padded on the *left* by zero. Thus,

```
reconstructArray = ArrayReshape[IntegerDigits[code, 2, 8*7], {8, 7}]
```